# Magento 2.4.3 Configurable Disappears From Catalog when simple count exceeds 325

Tags: configurable-product, catalog, magento2.4.3, indexer, missing

One for the Gurus!

I have a configurable with 3 Attributes: Product type, Colour and Height.
When I exceed 325 simple products within the configurable the product will disappear from the category it is assigned to but will remain available on front end either via direct url or search.

When i then remove about 10 simples and re-run indexer manually the product will eventually reappear, until I exceed 325 simples again.

Cron runs every minute without delays

No errors show in magento logs or mysql logs

my.conf:

- performance-schema=0
- innodb_file_per_table=1
- max_allowed_packet=268435456
- open_files_limit=40000 unix_socket=OFF
- innodb_buffer_pool_size=1024M

#MagentoTweaks optimizer_switch='rowid_filter=off' optimizer_use_condition_selectivity = 1 tmp_table_size=2G
max_heap_table_size=2G

I have increased memory well above requirements

Running with Elastic Search 7, with MariaDB 10.5.16, php 7.4

php ini

- Max Execution 18000
- Max input time 6000
- Max input vars 100000
- Memory Limit 3072M
- Post Max Size 256M

Have I hit a Magento limit?

At this stage I have run out of ideas, so any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Additional information request, please. 
RAM size, # cores, any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post TEXT results on justpaste.it and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
A) SELECT COUNT(*) FROM information_schema.tables;
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST; 
E) STATUS;  not SHOW STATUS, just STATUS;
G) SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS; 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Comment: Thanks for the request. Whilst I appreciate you may need more information i'm not comfortable giving out some of this server information publicly. Is there a particular setting that you are looking for that may help? The server I am using is of high spec: 4 Processors x
AMD EPYC 7542 32-Core Processor
Speed 2900.000 MHz
Cache 512 KB

Memory: 4974856k/11534336k available - if that helps.

Comment: Could you post TEXT results of first page of HTOP ;  we can go from there.

Comment: When you are above 325 simples, would run re-indexer make them appear two hours after re-index requested?

Comment: The following URL may provide some 'clues' for you about what is going on with your configurable.  JSON is apparently getting involved and JSON limits may be getting in your way.

Comment: Here is the URL - https://community.magento.com/t5/Magento-1-x-Hosting-Performance/Configurable-Product-Limitations/m-p/60348#M1288

Comment: I've re-indexed from command line several times with this plus cache purge on server and Cloudflare. In addition I have checked to make sure that the Configurable is listed in the correct tables so your json theory may be a good avenue to check. (Flat tables also unticked in magento catalog options). I presume that SQL is created when the categories are called. Any idea what the SQL actaully is?

Comment: Please also bear in mind that the configurable product DOES show correctly when going to its direct url. This problem is that its missing in the Category it's assigned to.

Comment: Additional: I don't show or need to show product options on the category page (it redirects to product page if options exist) - So question: Does the category page creation process initially run a query with all options before it is rendered/filtered down by the theme or other settings? If so, is it possible to limit the JSON to 1 product?

Comment: A 'General Log Analysis' for your specific situation might uncover the real problem.  View profile for contact info and make contact and we do have free Utility Scripts to assist with performance tuning.  Is the problem repeatable in your Magento TEST world?